# Curl, not getting page source code

Tags: php, curl

In this script curl is working fine. $output has the page but when I try to echo its source code it displays nothing. I think it has something to do with page headers. Any help!!

```
header('content-type:text/plain');
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/shiptrack/view.html/ref=TE_SIMP_typ?ie=UTF8&addressID=olqnkqjstjp&latestArrivalDate=1483848000&orderID=103-0753412-5410653&shipmentDate=1483706902&orderingShipmentId=4160817392100&packageId=1";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Why downvote .What's not clear.

Comment: when debugging, use var_dump , not echo. var_dump is guaranteed to give some output, what does var_dump say? (most likely, it says bool(false) , meaning that curl had an error, in which case, use curl_error($ch) to get more info)

Comment: seems you're running without error reporting, and you reference an undefined variable called $curl (because the variable you want is called $ch , $curl is undefined), the script crashes, but without error_reporting in php.ini , you just get a blank page and no error log - make sure php.ini contains `error_reporting=E_ALL`, and run the code again and the error should be obvious from the error log

Comment: @Bilal's edited answer has worked for me

Comment: @rajeev singh can pls accept my answer by clicking on that tick mark near votes...so it will be helpful to others too(When u accept it will turn into green tick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code..
Try this.

Remove
**header('content-type:text/plain');**

and replace your code with mine.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/shiptrack/view.html/ref=TE_SIMP_typ?ie=UTF8&addressID=olqnkqjstjp&latestArrivalDate=1483848000&orderID=103-0753412-5410653&shipmentDate=1483706902&orderingShipmentId=4160817392100&packageId=1";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

**EDIT**

Since you want `ctrl+u`

Here is the PHP code to fetch the html source code of any website specified. fopen function is used to open the website URL. stream_get_contents is used to read the opened URL. The fetched code is displayed inside a textarea.

```
$domain = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/shiptrack/view.html/ref=TE_SIMP_typ?ie=UTF8&addressID=olqnkqjstjp&latestArrivalDate=1483848000&orderID=103-0753412-5410653&shipmentDate=1483706902&orderingShipmentId=4160817392100&packageId=1';
$handle = fopen($domain, 'r');
$content = stream_get_contents($handle);
/**
// alternative to stream_get_contents
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $content .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
**/ 
fclose($handle);
/** 
 * print html content on textarea
 */
echo "<textarea rows='20' cols='80'>$content</textarea>";
```

output will be like this:
[image]

**OR**

> Also if you want to manipulate the retrieved page somehow, you might
>   want to try some php DOM parser. I find [PHP Simple HTML DOM
>   Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) very easy to use.

Comment: $output has the page but I want to get its html, that is where I am facing problem.

Comment: Rajeev singh i didn't get u.. can u elaborate??  i thought you had problem with ur curl

Comment: I want the html of the page so I can scrap some content from it.

Comment: @bilal. sorry I was not clear b4. my curl is workinf fine and the $output contains the page that I want but I want that page html so I acn scrap some content from it.

Comment: what exactly are u trying to do?

Comment: please try running the script once and you will understand. I want the html of the page. just run it once.

Comment: @RajeevSingh If yu have problem in english then you can explain in hindi.. The above code puts the source code of  the page in $output variable

Comment: @M A SIDDIQUI. then how come I am not getting the source code when I am echoing out $output.

Comment: did my answer helped u?

Comment: can make ma answer as accepted?? so that others would know it worked